# Is there a way to upload an image with the SOAP API into the Portfolio and see the URL in return?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, ampscript, images

I am trying to find a way to upload an image via API into the portfolio and then use that uploaded image in an email.

I am able to use the following AMPScript, %%= Image(customer_key) =%%, inserting the customer_key to reference the image.  However, I am not able to add inline styling or other attributes on that image tag, the AMPScript only seems to allow an ALT attribute.

I would like to avoid making a separate API call after the upload where I retrieve that same portfolio item, grab the URL and store the value in a Data Extension.

I am hoping that the new Content API will address this issue but in the meantime I would like to figure something out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the URL from what is returned in the Image function by doing this:

```
%%[
 set @imageTag = Image("ImageCustomerKey")
 set @regEx = "(?<=src=['""])(http[s]?://.*?)['""]"
 set @imageUrl = RegExMatch(@imageTag, @regEx, 1, "IgnoreCase")
]%%
imageTag: %%=v(@imageTag)=%%
imageUrl: %%=v(@imageUrl)=%%
```

From there, you can re-construct the tag in the form you want.